# DataTables - sort only selected columns?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I use DataTables (Table Plugin for jQuery) and use the possibility to sort the columns with a click.

However, I only want to use this option in selected columns. Other columns should not have the possibility to sort them.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the `<thead><th>`

```
<th data-orderable="false">Not sorted</th>
```

See https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html for a full example